# Taking the values from the emgu CudaHoughLinesDetector.Detect method

Tags: c#, .net, cuda, emgucv

I'm trying to take the values from a GpuMat created through the usage of the emgus http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/0ea81a16-a202-758c-2863-84d23d7fb8d1.htm method, that should give me data on lines that exist on a frame. However, I can't take the values from the output Emgu.CV.IOutputArray.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
 var cudaImage = new Mat(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1);

 GpuMat cudaResult = new GpuMat();

 cudaResult.Upload(cudaImage);

 var cudaDet = new Emgu.CV.Cuda.CudaHoughLinesDetector(rho, theta, thres);

 cudaDet.Detect(frame, cudaResult);
```

How can I take the values? Should I use another type of structure for the output?

Note: I already tried to translate to a normal Mat, but the data is null. (GpuMat -> Mat)